# Given $f(x)+f′′(x) = -2\sin x$, Prove $f'(x)\cos x=-f(x)\sin x+\cos^2x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

> Given $f$ is a function twice differentiable on $\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)+f′′(x)
>  = -2\sin x$ and $f(0) = 0$,  Prove that $f′(x)\cos x = -f(x)\sin x + \cos^2x$ .

What are the tips/tricks to solving this question. 
I tried letting the LHS of the proof be $h(x)$ then differentiating $h(x)$,  $h'(x) = f''(x)\cos x - f'(x)\sin x$, but it seems to be of no use to me as I cannot seem to equate this or replace $h'(x)$.

Comment: what is concerning is that we have $f(0) = f'(0)  = 0 \implies 0\cdot \cos(0) = -0\cdot \sin(0) + \cos^2(0)$ with the LHS being $0$ and the RHS being $1$.

Comment: oops corrected:D

Comment: You need the condition $f'(0)=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us continue with your idea
$$
f''(x) \cos (x) - f'\sin (x) = -f'(x)\sin(x) -f(x)\cos(x) -2\cos (x) \sin(x)
$$
using the original equation we have
$$
\left(-2\sin(x) -f(x)\right)\cos (x) - f'\sin (x) = -f'(x)\sin(x) -f(x)\cos(x) -2\cos (x)\sin (x) 
$$
on the LHS we have
$$
-2\sin(x)\cos(x) -f(x)\cos(x) -f(x)'\sin(x)
$$
which does equal the RHS.

Comment: Thanks so much!